# Is there a generic URL for my-user-page?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

For bookmarking I just use the specific path with embedded userid, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/14749/chris-noe. But I want to do this generically across the sister sites, via Greasemonkey. So I'm hoping there is kind of `/users/me` URL.

EDIT: My assumption is that the user is already authenticated on all the sisters sites, and therefore the URL does not need to specify user's identity.

Answer (score 3):

In my greasemonkey scripts, I just pull the href value from the "Jonathan Sampson" link up by my rep. This is globally-present, and thus always available to my gm-scripts.

```
var user_id = $("#hlinks a[href^='/users/recent/']")
                .next("a").attr("href").split("/")[2];
```

Comment: @Jonathan, good to know for intra-site navigation, but I want to jump off to the sister sites and land on my home pages there, where the userids are all different. I know that the links are available in the "accounts" tab, but I think ajax would be too expensive...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is an option for that auto-discovery.

Answer (score 2):

[sitename].com/users/[your user id on the site]

I have not seen any way to do a users/myname url because there is nothing stopping people from having the same username. Making the URL based off the username then would not be a good idea.

Comment: I think his point was that the keyword "me" would default to whatever data is saved in your session. That would mean though that nobody could use the name "me" :)

Comment: Fun fact, after your user ID, you can be anybody you'd like to be in the URL: I AM WILLIAM WALLACE! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/95589/william-wallace

Comment: @Eric, Yeah. When I learned about the optional second parameter, I began using it on a personal project - glorious!