# Is there a generic link to your site profile that doesn't require your user ID?

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks

Six years on, is this possible yet?

[Is there a generic URL for my-user-page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18475/175002)

I ask as I wanted to link up all the sites in the first list, here: [List of communities with base css updates completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253359/175002) but I can't without a generic link.

Unlike the first question though, I'm not suggesting we base it off of name, but the user id should be stored somewhere in the page request (?) in Django it's just `request.user` to get the user object. The site is Ruby on Rails, so I'm guessing it will be different but similar.

Not sure if this is currently possible so taggin as both [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current

This redirects to your (the logged-in user's) user page. The `/users/current` works across all sites. Also, if not logged in, it just redirects back to the home page - no ugly error page.